# Accessing a collection of many to many relationship and passing a specific part of the collection to an update view as old()

Tags: php, laravel, input, eloquent, view

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Currently learning Laravel and I am struggling quite a bit.

**Background**
I am trying to build a quotation/invoice application. I am able to create a quotation with products. The information is stored in a `pivot table`, `product_quote`. Please see migration below.

```
Schema::create('product_quote', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('quote_id');
        $table->integer('qty');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have a relationship of `many to many`.

Please see my `Quote Model`

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('qty');
}
```

Please see my `Product Model`

```
public function quotes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quote::class)->withPivot('qty');
}
```

I have a `form` where the quotation is populated by `products` that are `grouped`. Please see the products `migration`.

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('group');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The products to show in the group inside the form is determined by example:

```
$features = DB::table('products')->whereIn('group', array(32))->get();
```

Please see an example of how how an input on the quotation is setup in my `view`.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-system_features" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-system_features-tab">
                                <p class="p-2 text-center alert-info">Please select the required system features.</p>
                                @foreach($features as $feature)
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="{{$feature->id}}" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{$feature->code. ' ' .$feature->name}}</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div >
                                                <input name="{{$feature->id}}" id="{{$feature->id}}" type="number" min="0" max="1" class="form-control @error('${{$feature->id}}') is-invalid @enderror"
                                                       value="{{old($feature->id) ?? 0}}" autocomplete="{{$feature->id}}" required autofocus>
                                                @error('{{$feature->id}}')
                                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror

                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
```

As you can see above I am making use of `{{old() ?? 0}}` in my `input` `value = ""`. I do this because after performing logic and the user makes a mistake I use `Redirect::back->withInput()->with('error','msg')`.

After the quote is created, configured, logic performed and the data stored in there respective `tables`.
I have an option where you can edit the quote. I go to a `view`, where I can edit the clients details. I then send the data to a `Controller` where the client data is saved. I then go to the `quote view` where I then again get a chance to edit the quotation`.

**My problem**
Returning to the `quote view` to edit the quotation. **None of the old details are shown in the input fields.**

**I have made the following progress:**

```
$quote = Quote::query()->findOrFail($id);
```

To find the quote to edit.

```
$products = $quote->products;
```

To find the products for this quotation.

Performing `dd($products);` I get the products as below.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1295 ▼
#items: array:5 [▼
0 => App\Product {#1303 ▶}
1 => App\Product {#1304 ▶}
2 => App\Product {#1305 ▶}
3 => App\Product {#1306 ▶}
4 => App\Product {#1307 ▶}
 ]
}
```

When I access the collection I get for example. In `attributes` I get:

```
    #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 34
    "group" => 10
    "code" => "KX-TES824SA"
    "name" => "Main Unit"
    "price" => 3651.4243455746
    "created_at" => ""
    "updated_at" => ""
  ]
```

And in the same `relations` I get:

```
    #relations: array:1 [▼
    "pivot" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#1300 ▼
      +incrementing: false
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "product_quote"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "quote_id" => 7
        "product_id" => 34
        "qty" => 1
      ]
```

So I can access the information I need but how do I get it from there into the form where my `input value = old() ?? 0` is used.

Should I create a different `view` for `edit` and if so do I still use `input value = old() ?? 0`, if not how else do I return `errors` after logic is performed.

Sorry for the long question, I tried to keep it as short as possible but still providing all the information needed.

Answer (score 0):

The [`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-old) helper works as follows:

> #### `old()`
>
> The old function retrieves an old input value flashed into the
> session:
>
> ```
> $value = old('value');
>
> $value = old('value', 'default');
> ```

As you can see, the value is retrieved from the session.

In your case, when you try to update an item, the info is not being pulled from the session. You are pulling it from the database. That's why the `old()` doesn't return anything.

If you look again at the `old()` function definition, it accepts a second argument that can be used as a default value. I think you could reference the value there, something like this:

```
// ...
value="{{ old($feature->id, $feature->id ?? 0) }}"
// ...                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Try it, it may need a little adjustment but you get the general idea and why it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: Horma Thank you for the response Kenny, I understand how the old() function works and that it would not have just automatically pulled that information as I got it from the data base. My question is how can I get that information to come up in my input and still have a default? Because if the data was not stored it should default to 0.

If the default is not there the user would need to input a value into each field even if it is a zero. As all fields are required. This is not ideal in terms of user experience.

Comment: @WesselsW I don't fully understand your question. As I can see, there's three escenarios (1) Creation: In this case the $feature->id is inexistent so the value will be default to 0. (2) Update: When updating, the default value of the field will be the one pulled from the database. (3) Update after failing validation: After submitting the form with errors, the old value will pick up the one sent in the previous request because that will be stored in session, so the users wouldn't need to re-type the rest of the fields. Of course, in my example I just used 1 field, but you could replicate it

Comment: My biggest struggle at the moment is figuring out how to get the data as shown in the `dd($products);`assigned correctly so when in my `view` I go through the @foreach, that the correct qty from the `database` is shown in the `input value`. I reckon putting it in the second argument of the `old()` it would work, but first I need to get it assigned correctly. 

So in short Im cannot seem to use the data that I am able to retrieve (sigh) :)